# Hierarchies/structures in Azure Artifacts?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

we are migrating from Artifactory towards Azure Artifacts.
In Artifactory we have quite deep repository structure and hierarchies.

Now I am wondering how I can realize such structures/hierarchies in Azure Artifacts.

From what I have seen there are only feeds that are in a plain list.

Thank you

---

Added some more description:

We are developing software products and want to deliver them to the artifact storage. We have a platform product and multple variants of the base product for different customers and different hardware architectures. In Artifactory we have defined a structure so that we can easily browse and find the right variant of the product. Something like this:

```
 Platform
    Arm
        Prod Pf Arm
    Intel
        Prod Pf Intel
 Cust1
    Arm
       Product V1
    Intel
       Product V2
 Cust2
    Arm
        Prod V3
```

Comment: Azure Artifacts is different from Artifactory, maybe you can share the scenario about how you want to manage your packages so that I can try to figure out how to manage the feeds to meet your needs.

Comment: I extended the description with an example structure that we have in Artifactory at the moment.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. But Azure Devops Artifact doesn't support same package with different platform. So you may need two feeds, one for Arm and the other for Intel. Also, I'm not sure about your package type, azure devops feed support `nuget/python/npm/maven/universal` types. If your package is not nuget/python/npm/maven, then only the [universal package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=azuredevops) is available for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Artifacts doesn't have same repository structure and hierarchies like what Artifactory has.

In Azure Devops, we use [Organization + Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/about-projects?view=azure-devops) to manage the work. So in most scenarios, each project is corresponding to one module of one big product and the organization represents a big product. Or sometimes a project represents a product in which repos within it represents sub-modules of the project-level product.

Then Azure Devops provides [Organization-Scoped Feed and Project-Scoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/project-scoped-feeds?view=azure-devops) to manage the packages for the projects and organizations. We can [set permissions in Feed Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops) to determine who can access our feed, also [UpStream sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops) is a good option to create a bridge between feeds. (If feedB is feedA's upstream source, then people who can access FeedA, can access FeedB indirectly via FeedA).

You can find the structure in Azure Artifacts is quite different from that in Artifactory. You can learn more about Azure Artifacts from [these documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/?view=azure-devops). Hope it helps :)